# include string class on c++ and eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, class

i have a c++ project on eclipse and i can to use the string class in main file, but when i add a new file to the project I can not use any class.

I add file how: New-> Source file and select Template: Defaul c++ template source.

This is error src/Common.cpp:8:17: error: ‘string’ was not declared in this scope

and in src/AC.cpp all ok

thanks very much

Thanks larsman my simple code is:

AC.cpp -> all ok

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string j = !!!Hello World!!!;
cout << j << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
return 0;
}
```

Common.cpp -> src/Common.cpp:8:17: error: ‘string’ was not declared in this scope

```
#include <string>
void PrintTrace(string message)
{
    string j = !!!Hello World!!!;
cout << j << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
}
```

both files are the same project.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <string>
```

You have to include this header in all modules that use `std::string`.

Comment: thank now all ok, i add: using namespace std; but whith std::string no work

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding the include directive `#include <string>` (as stated by larsmans) you must refer to it using its fully qualified name `std::string`.

If you want to use `string` only, add `using std::string;` to each `.cpp` source file where it is used (you could also add `using namespace std;` [but this is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)).